# Suspend desktop from the lock screen

Tags: 14.04, suspend, lock-screen

I often leave my desktop PC running to serve some media via Plex. When I'm done watching, all I want to do is suspend the PC. By then, it has automatically locked, and annoyingly won't respond to me pressing the keyboard sleep button. I'm required to turn on my monitor (which starts slow), log in, and then suspend.

I would much prefer if I could just push the sleep button while the PC is locked. Can I change some setting so it's allowed?

Comment: Note: I often type in my password, hit enter, then sleep, without turning on my monitor. It's extra annoying when this doesn't work and I need to turn it on after all to check what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Go to System Settings -- > Brightness & Lock panel from the Unity Launcher.

Where you will find a tick option like **"Require my password when waking from suspend"**. Just **uncheck the tick option**. I hope that this will do the needful